# Send transaction with iota.lib.csharp on VS2015

Tags: c#, blockchain

With the decentralized blockchain technology rising i wanted to play a bit with iota in c#. Ive found the csharp lib of the iota api and trying to send a transaction but got a problem i couldnt figure out without help.

Here is my code:

```html
         private  void test()
        {

            IotaApi iotaApi = new IotaApi("node.iotawallet.info", 14265);
            GetNodeInfoResponse nodeInfo = iotaApi.GetNodeInfo();


            List<Transfer> transfers = new List<Transfer>();
            transfers.Add(new Transfer("testseed", 0, "JUSTANOTHERTEST", null));
       

            bool[] str = iotaApi.SendTransfer("XXXXXXXXM8SNQJQBSJPLPOYFNVFXXXXXXXXXXXX9HBCWCZXWYNAIUAWGENQYU9SRQGJQZNEBWFPOQLBHX", 4,1, transfers.ToArray(), null, null);

        }
```

When i run it, i get " Not a transfer array" exception  on iotaApi.SendTransfer using a console application on VS2015
I traced it down to the function "CheckTransferArray" which is called by Sendtransfer but couldnt figure out what i was doing wrong.(information here https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.csharp/wiki/M_Iota_Lib_CSharp_Api_Utils_InputValidator_CheckTransferArray)

As i couldnt find much documentation for c# and this lib i copied the test methodes and tryed to get it working without luck.
I also noticed that the last update on github was some months ago, so my question is : 
Is there a solution or did i failed to understand something ? Or is the lib not up to date? Would realy appreciate if somebody could help me.

Comment: `iota.lib.csharp` has not yet been updated for the hashing changes to thwart the attack found by MIT. So, at the moment, to run against public servers you'd have to use either iota.lib.js or iota.lib.java.

Comment: Apart from that, the `"testseed"` of your sample code may not be a seed, but has to be an address (with checksum) associated to a seed.

Comment: And your seed "FF9OYDOWM8SNQJQBSJPLPOYFNVFSSPXEUPUFIDI9HBCWCZXWYNAIUAWGENQYU9SRQGJQZNEBWFPOQLBHX" contains an 8, which is invalid in a seed (only A-Z and 9)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i know its invalid bcause i edited it in a lazy way, Ill try the java lib instead.